# Getting Skype Identity In Bot Framework?

Tags: c#, skype, botframework

I have successfully written a simple bot application have it communicating within Skype.

I've tried to personalise a welcome message to a user when they say 'Hello'. However I can't seem to get their Skype display name or email from the 'From' ChannelAccount field. The name and address have strange values. For example for one user they return something in the format '8:skypename' and for another user they return '4:564:differentskypename'. The values are consistent for a specific user, but the format is different.

Does anyone know if you can get at the user's basic Skype information directly? Or do you need separate calls in order to get it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no support for getting a user's Skype information (other than their Skype handle).  For the handle, simply strip of the prefix (i.e. "8:").  (These prefixes are are the ones returned by the Skype api).

Comment: Do you know if this is a planned feature at all?

Comment: At Build 2016 they said the users' information would be available to the bot, and not just obfuscated IDs. -- After stripping the prefix I'm left with a crazy looking base64 string.  That is definitely not the Skype handle I signed up with. -- How do you at least get the actual handle?

Answer (score 0):

Skype bots receive a unique user identity such as 29:2hJJkjmGn4ljB2X7YYEju-sgFwgvnISvE6G3abGde8ts - which is different to a user's Skype ID (referred as handle above). Each message also contains the user's display name which should be used for.

e.g.

```
"from": {
"id": "29:2hJJkjmGn4ljB2X7YYEju-sgFwgvnISvE6G3abGde8ts",
"name": "Display Name"
}
```