# Persistent Skype user ID across individual and group chat.

Tags: botframework

When a bot chat with a user individually or in a group, the API returns different user ids. How can I know it's the same person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skype user's information fields looks like the following `"from": { "id": "29:1DwlGVzj.....", "name": "My Skype Name" }` (and bot's id is `"28:appId"`).

This user id is a specific to your bot, it is a hash but the way it is generated is not known (not open-source). But this id is identidical for a unique user when talking individually with the bot or inside a group conversation with the same bot.

See sample here, I just checked:

Direct message between user and bot:
[image]

Group conversation including same user and same bot:
[image]

I've hidden some characters of the id in case of... but I confirm they are exactly the same values.

---

See also questions around the same problems:

- For more details about the different channels and the ID format: [Authenticate user across channels in Microsoft bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876191/authenticate-user-across-channels-in-microsoft-bot-framework/44880931#44880931)
- [Get Skype ID from Activity object Bot Framework V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992661/get-skype-id-from-activity-object-bot-framework-v3?rq=1)
- [Getting Skype Identity In Bot Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617144/getting-skype-identity-in-bot-framework)

Comment: you are right, the issue wasn't the Bot Framework but the library I am using to send message. https://botman.io/ Thanks Nicolas R